# How to use Helpshift Embeddable Support Fragments Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I am building an Android app that uses the Helpshift API. It was all working, but I am currently trying to move everything into a TabLayout, using Fragments and an ActionBar. I made a mini app to figure out functionality of the fragments without messing everything else up. I have a home screen where you click a button and it starts the activity containing the TabLayout with the Fragments. I cannot figure out how to make the embeddable support fragments show up in the TabLayout. I'm pretty new to Android, so sorry if my code is not the best. Right now the placeholder is not being replaced in the fragment transaction, and I can't figure out why. I would greatly appreciate any advice! Thank you :) Let me know if I can provide anything else

Here is my main activity class (Helpshift info has been redacted for privacy reasons, hopefully my issue can still be fixed)

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context mContext;
    public ConstraintLayout layout;
    Activity goToFragment;
    public Button start;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        goToFragment = MainActivity.this;

       start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
       start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick (View view) {
               launchFragments();
           }
       });

        //HELPSHIFT SET UP
        Core.init(All.getInstance());
        InstallConfig installConfig = new InstallConfig.Builder()
                        .setScreenOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE)
                .setEnableInAppNotification(true)
                .build();
        try {
            Core.install(getApplication(),
                    "****APIKEY*****",
                    "****DOMAIN*****",
                    "****APPID******", installConfig);

        } catch (InstallException e) {
            android.util.Log.e("Helpshift", "install call : ", e);
        }

    }

    private void launchFragments() {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(mContext, HomeTab.class);
        intent1.putExtra("fragmentNumber", 0);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
    }

Here is my ViewPager Adapter class:

        public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager){
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
    }
```

Here is my fragment activity class:

```
public class HomeTab extends AppCompatActivity {
//    ImageButton FindCareButton;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
public Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    Intent intent1 = getIntent();
    int var = intent1.getIntExtra("fragmentNumber", 0);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(var);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    if (findViewById(R.id.placeholder) != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            return;
        }
        Fragment faqFragment = new Fragment();
        faqFragment = Support.getFAQsFragment(HomeTab.this);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.placeholder, faqFragment).commit();
    }
   }




    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FAQTab(), "FAQ");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    }
```

Here is my FAQTab class:

```
public class FAQTab extends Fragment {
public FAQTab(){
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.faq_tab, container, false);

}

}
```

For layouts, my faq_tab layout is an empty FrameLayout with id "placeholder"
My home_screen layout is a ConstraintLayout with a button (id "button") 
And here is my activity_main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sasha.fragment_tester.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/BarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```